# How to correct error when sampling Cauchy distribution

Tags: python, numpy, transform, sampling, inverse

I'm trying to sample values from a Cauchy distribution, using what is called (I think) `inverse transform sampling`. My program is as follows:

```
from numpy import*
from matplotlib.pyplot import*
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def f(x):
    return 1 / (pi*(1+x**2)) # Cauchy

x = linspace(-6,+6,100)
dx = x[1]-x[0]
cdf = cumsum(f(x))*dx

plt.plot(x,cdf)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('CDF')
plt.show()

from_cdf_to_x = interp1d(cdf, x)
cdf_new = np.random.uniform(0,1,100)
x_sampled = from_cdf_to_x(cdf_new)
```

The plot looks fine, but I get the following error in the 2nd part which I don't understand: `A value in x_new is above the interpolation range`.
What does it mean, in my case, and what would be the proper way to correct it? No matter how much I search, I don't see what is not correct in the program I made...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of your array cdf_new is from 0 to 1.0, but the Cauchy cumulative distribution asymptotically approaches 1 without reaching it, thus the interpolation doesn't cover the full range of the uniform distribution. You need to reduce the top range of cdf_new and/or increase the range of x when you generate the Cauchy cumulative distribution

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def f(x):
    return 1 / (np.pi*(1+x**2)) # Cauchy

x = np.linspace(-100,+100,1000)
dx = x[1]-x[0]
cdf = np.cumsum(f(x))*dx

plt.plot(x,cdf)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('CDF')
plt.show()

from_cdf_to_x = interp1d(cdf, x)
cdf_new = np.random.uniform(0.05,0.95,10000)
x_sampled = from_cdf_to_x(cdf_new)
plt.hist(x_sampled, bins=20)
plt.show()
```

Here is the normal distribution that you were expecting:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. By the way, following your answer, I used again `x = np.linspace(-6,+6,1000)` but with `cdf_new = np.random.uniform(min(cdf),max(cdf),10000)` and it works also well. I think it is still possible to do this?

Comment: Yes, that is definitely a better way to do it as long as you are happy with where the min and max are.

If my answer helped you, would you mind accepting it please?